# How to add configuration to Logging Agent from Docker Container?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to run a docker container on Compute Engine, everything works fine, my PHP app is correctly returning all data but i want to Increase log verbosity.

For now I've added two config files for fluentd inside a container config dir:

- This one for nginx:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  format nginx
  path /var/log/feedbacks/nginx-access.log
  pos_file /var/lib/google-fluentd/pos/nginx-access.pos
  read_from_head true
  tag nginx-access
</source>

<source>
  @type tail
  format none
  path /var/log/feedbacks/nginx-error.log
  pos_file /var/lib/google-fluentd/pos/nginx-error.pos
  read_from_head true
  tag nginx-error
</source>
```

- And this one for PHP log output :

```
<source>
  @type tail
  format /^\[(?<time>[\d\-]+ [\d\:]+)\] (?<channel>.+)\.(?<level>(DEBUG|INFO|NOTICE|WARNING|ERROR|CRITICAL|ALERT|EMERGENCY))\: (?<message>[^\{\}]*) (?<context>(\{.+\})|(\[.*\])) (?<extra>(\{.+\})|(\[.*\]))\s*$/
  path /var/log/feedbacks/structured.log
  pos_file /var/lib/google-fluentd/pos/feedbacks.pos
  read_from_head true
  tag feedbacks
</source>
```

I've mounted this 2 config files as follow with the corresponding logs files:

- container path: `/usr/src/app/var/logs/`, host path: `/var/log/feedbacks/`, mode: r/w
- container path: `/usr/src/app/docker/runnable/fluentd/`, host path: `/etc/google-fluentd/config.d/`, mode: r/w

But when I /bin/bash to these directories inside the `stackdriver-logging-agent` there is nothing inside, maybe i'm missing something ...

Thanks for helping !

Comment: For information when i do `docker ps` inside the GCE Instance i have these 2 lines :
`klt-instance-3-uwtu my-image "/entrypoint.sh"`
and `stackdriver-logging-agent gcr.io/stackdriver-agents/stackdriver-logging-agent:0.2-1.5.33-1-1 "/entrypoint.sh /usr…"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stackdriver-logging-agent` reads a container's logs through the equivalent of `docker logs [container]`. This provides a consistent API for processes on the host OS to gather container logs.

By default, the container's stdout|stderr are sent to `docker logs` and it's this stream that the `stackdriver-logging-agent` is collecting and onsending to the Stackdriver service.

IIUC correctly, you'd need to ensure that your PHP app is generating the richer logs and that these are being sent to stdout|stderr.

If you were to use Nginx's stock Docker image, it does this:

```sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 May  8 03:01 access.log -> /dev/stdout
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 May  8 03:01 error.log -> /dev/stderr
```

See Docker's documentation here:

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/

I was unable to find a good explanation for this for Container OS on Google's site.

Comment: Thanks that was real helpful, at first I've installed the `google-fluentd` agent inside my container which worked well but it used more CPU.